# Third Party UI Web controls 'compatible' with ASP.NET Core Boilerplate?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I'm seeking recommendations on any 3rd party/open source Web UI Controls that provide features but do not interfere with the good work done in this template.

I have tried Telerik

```
<PackageReference Include="Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core" Version="2018.1.117" />
```

but that seems to interfere with the styling/behaviour of the other non-telerik controls. i even commented out all telerik styling etc but it's just so intrusive.

Anyway any thoughts would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try DevExpress controls. It's pretty new and good. And bootstrap compliant... see  https://demos.devexpress.com/aspnetcore-bootstrap/